# IOS Memory Warning and crash while comparing phone numbers from 2 large arrays

Tags: ios7.1

I need to compare an array coming from server with my addressbook array and check for same phone numbers, if numbers aren't common, i need to add the element in my address book. Both arrays may be huge in size, while comparing the phone numbers in nested for loops, I get huge memory leaks, and memory increases to more than 1 gb in case of large data, thus the app crashes due to memory pressure while running on a device. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show an example of your loop?

Comment: yes. 2 arrays one for addressbook, one is the array being fetched from web.

Comment: this is the code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942787/ios-memory-pressure-while-comparing-two-large-arrays

Comment: Can anyone tell me the solution?